# Can web workers be used in this scenario?

Tags: javascript, web-worker

Suppose I have a very large array, and several functions that utilize it.

Each function needs (read-only) access to all elements of the array.

I would like to execute these functions in parallel, using web workers.

I can't make copies of the array because it's too large, so I need to pass it as a transferable object to all of the workers.

But from what I've read, this is not possible because once I pass the array to the first worker as a transferable object, I can't pass it to a second worker.

Is this correct? If so, is there any way to parallelize my code in this scenario?

Comment: `Is this correct?` yes - `If so, is there any way to parallelize my code in this scenario?` who can say without seeing any code - it's just a guessing game

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a SharedWorker sounds like it would work although I am not sure
[SharedWorker docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SharedWorker)